# postgresql -replace everything that is not = 'some string'

Tags: postgresql

How in postgresql replace all instances of a row in a database column?

Let's say I want to replace all instances not equal to '1', '2' by '0' for example.

```
select regexp_replace(some_field,not in ('0','1','2'),'0') from table_name
```

not working

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What is an *instance of a row*? Please provide sample data and  desired results as tabular text. You might also want to show your current attempt.

Comment: in a field of type text there are values ​​'1', '2', all sorts of characters, of which there are a lot, and empty cells ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) for this:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN some_field IN ('0',
                               '1',
                               '2') THEN some_field
           ELSE '0'
       END AS some_field_new
FROM test;
```

Comment: what does "a" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE schema_name.table_name SET column_name = '0' WHERE column_name not in ('1', '2');
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-update.html

If this is not what you need, please provide more details, including data and expected result.